# Ignore duplicate entry from table column in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this pretty interesting problem that I'm struggling to find a proper solution for. I have this API that returns the following object.

```
const backendObject = [
    { name: "user1", item: "shirt" },
    { name: "user1", item: "pants" },
    { name: "user2", item: "shirt" },
    { name: "user2", item: "pants" },
    { name: "user2", item: "socks" }
  ];
```

I'm supposed to display these results in table form which is pretty straight forward. The challenge comes in the fact that I'd like to display the user column and return the duplicate names as empty. as such:

```
| User  | Item  |
| user1 | shirt |
|       | pants |
| user2 | shirt |
|       | pants |
|       | socks |
```

this is what my code looks like as of now:

```
function App() {
  const backendObject = [
    { name: "user1", item: "shirt" },
    { name: "user1", item: "pants" },
    { name: "user2", item: "shirt" },
    { name: "user2", item: "pants" },
    { name: "user2", item: "socks" }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Item</th>
          </tr>
          {
            backendObject.map((data, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>{data.name}</td>
                  <td>{data.item}</td>
                </tr>
            ))
          }
        </table>

      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and my output looks like this:

```
| User  | Item  |
| user1 | shirt |
| user1 | pants |
| user2 | shirt |
| user2 | pants |
| user2 | socks |
```

Could someone shed some light in what approach I could take? I may have hit a mental wall right now.

Comment: Probably you should do a `groupBy` on `User` column & then iterate over the `Item` inside the react table itself
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would go is to reconstruct the data structure to respect what you want in the table:

```js
const backendObject = [{
    name: "user1",
    item: "shirt"
  },
  {
    name: "user1",
    item: "pants"
  },
  {
    name: "user2",
    item: "shirt"
  },
  {
    name: "user2",
    item: "pants"
  },
  {
    name: "user2",
    item: "socks"
  }
];

const grouped = backendObject.reduce((ac, {
  name,
  item
}) => ({ ...ac,
  [name]: [...(ac[name] || []), item]
}), {})


const rows = Object.entries(grouped).reduce((ac, [user, v]) => [
  ...ac,
  ...v.map((item, i) => ({
    user: i === 0 ? user : '',
    item
  }))
], [])

console.log(rows)
```

Comment: How would you handle multiple if adding multiple keys? I understand for just users and items. But if they were to add another key I think it wouldn't work as well. Apologize if I'm sounding confusing I'm still fairly new at this.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to restructure/normalize the object and go from there. For example:

```js
const object = {
  user1: ['shirt', 'pants', 'short'],
  user2: ['pants', 'socks']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function App() {
  const backendObject = [
    { name: 'user1', item: 'shirt' },
    { name: 'user1', item: 'pants' },
    { name: 'user2', item: 'shirt' },
    { name: 'user2', item: 'pants' },
    { name: 'user2', item: 'socks' },
  ];

  const userGroupedDate = backendObject.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    if (accumulator[currentValue.name] === undefined) {
      accumulator[currentValue.name] = [];
    }
    accumulator[currentValue.name].push(currentValue.item);
  }, {});


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Item</th>
          </tr>
          {
            userGroupedDate
              .items()
              .map(([name, items], index) =>
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>{name}</td>
                  <td>{items.map(eachItem => <div> {eachItem} <br/></div>)}</td>
                </tr>,
              )

          }
        </table>

      </header>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Question, for this approach. How would this function work? I'm trying to wrap my head around its logic.

Comment: userGroupedDate, I meant the variable.